# Silent login when token expired in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I use the below code but it does not work.

When I entered to homepage the log is not display as I want (In console log, it show : first then last, and the last is second) so It always return token invalid because it does not run in order. I dont know where I wrong.
Please help me. Thank you all !

```
logIn(identifi : string, password : string ) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With');    
    let body = {
      "user_id" : identifi,
      "password" : password
    };
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(api.logIn, body, options).map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }  

  checkToken() {
    this.storage.get('user').then((user) => {
      if(user) {
        this.token = user.token;
        this.token_date = user.token_date - 100;
        this.currentDate = new Date();
        this.expDate = new Date(this.token_date * 1000);
        if (this.currentDate <= this.expDate) {
          // token expired, login again     
          console.log('first');  
          this.logIn(user.user_id, user.password).subscribe(
            data => {
              this.storage.set("user", userInfo);  
              console.log('second');
              return  userInfo.token;
            },
            err => {
              console.log(err);
            });
        }
      }
    })
  }

  getDataHomepage(retailerId: number,pageIndex: number) {
    this.checkToken();
    console.log('last');
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token);
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get(api.promotion + '?retailer_id=' + retailerId + '&page=' + pageIndex, options).map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are calling checkToken() in getDataHomepage and not waiting for it to finish and moving forward to call get data homepage. (javascript doesen't wait for checkToken() to finish but it goes forward and calls the get in getDataHomepage)

You have to call this.http.get data from homepage after the login and with "after" I mean in the subscribtion of login.
Or try using the "flatMap" described [hier](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/http/search_with_flatmap.html)

The second suspicious place in your code seams to me this part:

```
        if (this.expDate === this.currentDate) {
      // token expired, login again
```

I think instead of === you have to use <= or >= but you have to test that.

Comment: I've changed to if(this.currentDate <= this.expDate), the function getToken() still run last. so I cant get the token. Any ideas ?

Comment: See my other post, because I can't add her in the comment code snippets https://stackoverflow.com/a/46603857/3853300

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look you do one thing wrong with your date.
You say if date = date what you can better do is:

```
if(this.currentDate <= this.expDate){
//login }
else{
//logout with expired message }
```

Or visa versa.

A session you mostly use to expire the session so it not exist forever. If you not let it expire why you you make a session?

Answer (score 0):

Like I said you have two bugs, what you now changed is the solution (maybe, I don't know, you have to test it) for the second problem, the first problem is that you have to call checkToken, login and getDataHompage as nested Observables something like this:

```
      logIn(identifi : string, password : string ) {
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
      headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With');    
      let body = {
        "user_id" : identifi,
        "password" : password
      };
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      return this.http.post(api.logIn, body, options).map((res:Response) => res.json());
    }  

    checkToken() {
      this.storage.get('user').then((user) => {
        if(user) {
          this.token = user.token;
          this.token_date = user.token_date - 100;
          this.currentDate = new Date();
          this.expDate = new Date(this.token_date * 1000);
          if (this.currentDate <= this.expDate) {
            // token expired, login again     
            console.log('first');  
            return this.logIn(user.user_id, user.password).map((res:Response) => res.json());
              /*  .subscribe(
                  data => {
                    this.storage.set("user", userInfo);  
                    console.log('second');
                    return  userInfo.token;
                  },
                  err => {
                    console.log(err);
                  });*/
          }else{
            return Observable.of(user);
          }
        }
      })
    }

    getDataHomepage(retailerId: number,pageIndex: number) {
      this.checkToken().subscribe((res)=>{
        console.log('last');
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token);
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.get(api.promotion + '?retailer_id=' + retailerId + '&page=' + pageIndex, options).map((res:Response) => res.json());
      },(err)=>{});
    }
```

just to have an Idea, for elegant solution use flatMap and forkJoin like described [hier](http://blog.danieleghidoli.it/2016/10/22/http-rxjs-observables-angular/)